# How to show that $\overline{X}_n$ is not a sufficient statistic in a Laplace-product-model?

Tags: statistics, parameter-estimation

We consider the statistical model given by the Lebesgue-density
$$p([x_1,\ldots,x_n],\theta)=\frac{1}{2^n}\exp\left(-\sum_{i=1}^n|x_i-\theta|\right),~~x:=[x_1,\ldots,x_n]\in\mathbb{R}^n$$
for fixed $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $n\geq 2$, with unknown parameter $\theta\in\mathbb{R}$.

How can I see directly (without Pitman–Koopman–Darmois) that the arithmetic mean $T(x)=\overline{x}_n$ is not a sufficient statistic for $\theta$?

Using the factorisation theorem would essentially amount to showing that a representation of the form
$$\sum_{i=1}^n |x_i-\theta|=g(x)+h(\overline{x}_n,\theta)$$
is impossible - it certainly seems that way but I don't see a very clear argument that I'm not just "not smart enough" to choose $g$ and $h$.

Alternatively, I suppose one could directly compare probabilities; e.g. for $n=2$ we have
$$P(X_1\leq 0 \mid \overline{X}_2=t)=P(X_2\geq 2 \mid \overline{X}_2=t)$$
and again it strongly looks like this probability depends on $\theta$, but to be sure that would have to be checked by looking at the resulting conditional densities.

Is there a more effective approach?